# In Dojo how to add node to a tree in a sorted way?

Tags: dojo

In my Dojo application, I had a tree with nodes sorted by their name. Like this :
[image: Tree nodes sorted]

I already built a New form addition, and it can add a new node to this tree, but always at the bottom. Is there a way to insert this newly added node to the store in a correct sorted position? So if I am about to add `000-011 - Biaya Teknis Pengacara` to this tree, it should be ended up this way :
[image: sorted]

To achieve this, currently I must refresh my browser. Surely, this is not what all user wanted.. :)

For the code addition of node itself, here it is:

```
//TOFIX : add in a sorted way
                        akunStore.newItem(
                            {"id":data.id.toString(),"name":data.name},
                            {"parent": groupsModel.root, "attribute":"groups"}
                        );
                        akunStore.save();
                        akunStore.fetch();
```

I add the `fetch()` as shown above, but it didn't work, currently.

Comment: Did you try to call fetch() on your store after you added your item to it ?

Comment: @Philippe : I edit my answer to post the code to add new item to the store. Is that the right way to call fetch()?

Answer (score 3):

Use the sort attribute in your call to the fetch() method of your data store. Try something like :

```
akunStore.fetch({
    sort: [
        { attribute: "youFirstSortField" },
        { attribute: "aSecondSortField" }
    ]
});
```

You can also specify a descending order by adding "descending : true" in your sort params... more on that here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/sorting.html#quickstart-data-usingdatastores-sorting

Comment: This is cool!
I haven't tried this, but yet accept this as the answer. Thanks again @Philippe!

I'll report the outcome of this code

Comment: Sorry :) It didn't work. I've read this : http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-Tree-td192214.html and I think to make the store work if it's connected to a tree, we must do more code..